# HTML5 video player pauses in mobile devices, on opening new tab

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have developed an HTML5 video player for mobile devices. It plays well when I am in that tab. But as soon as I open new tab or switch to some other tab, it stops playing and appears in a frozen state. This is happening to me on all android as well as IPads. 
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks.